# Looking for a Unicode character: keyboard glyph for zero-width non-joiner

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I am looking for the Unicode character of a dashed line with an inverted arrow on top. The arrow is a triangle with a corner intersecting with the dashed line. This character is the keyboard symbol for the *zero-width non-joiner* character (U+200C). While zero-width non-joiner Unicode is easy to find, its corresponding keyboard symbol has been impossible to find.

Below is a screenshot of a Bengali keyboard on iOS, which displays the character in question in blue:

[image: Zero-width non-spacer selected on a Bengali keyboard on iOS]

To be clear, I am not asking for the Unicode for the zero-width non-joiner character, which I know is U+200C. Instead I am asking for the Unicode for the keyboard symbol which represents the zero-width non-joiner. Does anyone know how I can find the Unicode for this character?

Comment: The glyph will be part of the SF font for the Bengali language. It is a screen implementation only & will never actually 'type'. It may not exist as a typeable glyph, though you can still search it using my method below. I don't have Bengali as a user interface option here, so I can't test.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty confident that there is no Unicode character or combination intended for this very purpose, but you can get something visually similar that is somewhat semantically fitting, by combining one of:

- U+205E: vertical four dots: ⁞
  This one is intended for word breaks (which is were I would usually expect a ZWNJ), albeit undesireable ones.
- U+2999: dotted fence: ⦙

and one of:

- U+030C: combining caron: ̌
- U+1AB3: combining downwards arrow: ᪳

The second character is combining, i.e., it ideally should display above the first one, but you cannot rely on this to work with every font, in particular since this is not an intended combination. Here is how the combinations render on your machine on this site:

> ⁞̌   ⦙̌̌   ⁞᪳   ⦙᪳

Answer (score 0):

Tap the plus sign next to the zero width non joiner

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.